# Unable to retrieve data from XML using linq to xml with multiple namespaces

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml, xml-database

I am unable to retrieve the data from XML looks like its I might be missing

The data I need to retrieve looks like this:

```
 <rs:data>
    <z:row billno='B0033582' billdtm='2012-05-21T22:57:02' tab_room='        ' waiter='SUP   ' pax='1' discount='.00000000'
    billdisamt='.00000000'   />
```

i am unable to retrive the data because of this `<z:row` vs `<row`

Namespace details

```
<xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
    xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
```

If i change this to row i can retrieve the data, is it possible to retrieve the row information when the row starts with `<z:row` `z:` is a i guess the namespace reference as given here `xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'` .

Please help me way to get the data out

Comment: this error comes when there is no root element try adding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`  at the top of your xml document

Comment: Have you properly declared the Xml namespace for your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was quite simple,

Just make these small changes, add these at the top

```
Imports <xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'>
Imports <xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
```

This should contain your namespace information generally available in the first few rows of the xml file

and then for the element which is referred with the namespace
just add z: referred about `<z:row>`

I could not find a solution in spite of searching all over, hopefully others would find this useful.